# regarding long and float

Tags: java

i was developing the below code

```
static String m(float i) {
    return "float";
}

static String m(double i) {
    return "double";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a1 = 1;
    long b1 = 2;
    System.out.print(m(a1) + "," + m(b1));
}
```

Both results in output float, float , what the reason behind that please advise and how can I call double please advise thanks a lot.

Comment: by making the type of the variable being passed `double` :)

Comment: it's **expected** to get **unexpected** results when you pass **unexpected** type of values as arguments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
    System.out.print(m(1f)+","+ m(2d));
```

why are you creating an int and long to test it? Well, what is actually happening is that both parameters are converted to float by default.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:** Java can automatically widen `int`s and `long`s to both `float`s and `double`s, but Java will choose to widen to a `float` because it is smaller (in terms of memory footprint) than a `double`. You can call the `double` version of the method by explicitly casting the argument to a `double`:

```
System.out.print(m((double)a1) + "," + m((double)b1));
```

**Long answer:** Each primitive data type in Java has a size (measured in bytes), which determines how much information (or rather, what *range of values*) a given primitive can hold. The table below shows the sizes of some of Java's primitive data types:

```
byte     1 byte
short    2 bytes
char     2 bytes
int      4 bytes
float    4 bytes
long     8 bytes
double   8 bytes
```

Java will automatically "widen" values for you in certain situations, following some [well-defined rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) from the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html). The following widening primitive conversions are performed by Java automatically:

- `byte` to `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
- `short` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
- `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
- `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
- `long` to `float` or `double`
- `float` to `double`

The other rules that are applicable to this situation are:

1. Widening does not lose information about the overall *magnitude* of the numeric value.
2. Widening from an integral type to another integral type does not lose any information at all; the numeric value is preserved exactly.
3. Widening an `int` or `long` value to a `float`, or of a `long` value to a `double` may result in a *loss of precision*.

For example, Java can safely widen an `int` to a `long` without changing the numeric value at all, because both are integral types and a `long` is larger than an `int` (see rule 2). Java can also widen an `int` to a `float`, but there might be a loss of *precision*. The sample code below demonstrates this loss of precision.

```
public static void foo(float f) {
    System.out.println(f);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 123;
    int b = 1234567890;
    foo(a);
    foo(b);
}
```

The first call to `foo(float)` prints "123.0" as expected. The `int` value "123" is widened to the `float` value "123.0". The second call prints "1.23456794E9", which makes sense when you take rule 3 into account. The value "1234567940" is the same *magnitude as* but less *precise than* "1234567890".

The other piece of information that is key here: when multiple overloaded methods are present, Java determines which method to call by choosing the method with the **smallest** parameter type (in terms of memory footprint) such that the given argument is capable of being widen to the parameter type. In other words, the number you pass to the method must be capable of being widened to the parameter type of the method, *and* if multiple overloaded methods satisfy that requirement, Java will choose the method whose parameter type is of the smallest size.

In your case, you are passing an `int` and a `long` to one of two overloaded methods. Java will look at methods `m(float)` and `m(double)` to determine which method to call. An `int` can be widened to a `float` *and* a `double`, but a `float` (4 bytes) is smaller than a `double` (8 bytes), so Java will choose to call `m(float)`. The same is true when you call the method with a `long` argument: `float` is chosen because it's the smallest data type that a `long` can be widened to.

Comment: +1 exactly why Java "widens" a 8-byte `long` into a 4-byte `float` is a mystery to me.  I suspect its historical.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call the `double` version, make it explicitly a double:  `m((double)a1)`

Take a look at the [JLS §8.4.9 - Method Overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9)

Answer (score 1):

> how can I call double?

Use a `double` variable

```
double d = 3.3;
m(d);
```